# efficiently check if values in one column belong to the threshold defined by two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

The goal of this question is efficiently improve the execution time of the problem I will now detail:

I have a df like this one:

```
df

 |   | min  | max   | value |
 |---|------|-------|-------|
 | 0 | 1.0  | 10.0  | 15    |
 | 1 | 50.0 | 100.0 | 20    |
 | 2 | 30.0 | 50.0  | 40    |
 | 3 | 10.0 | 90.0  | 91    |
 | 4 | NaN  | NaN   | 1000  |
```

And what I want to check is if the values of the value column are within the threshold defined by the min and max columns.

If min and max columns are equal to Nan then we consider that the value in column value is within the threshold.

To solve this I have created the following code:

```
In[1]:
def boundary(row):
    if row['value'] <= row['min'] or row['value'] >= row['max']:
        return 'out of range'
    else:
        return 'ok'
```

```
In[2]:
%%timeit
df["boundary"] = df.apply(lambda row: boundary(row), axis=1)
```

```
Out[2]:
959 µs ± 21.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

|   | min  | max   | value | boundary     |
| - | ---- | ----- | ----- | ------------ |
| 0 | 1.0  | 10.0  | 15    | out of range |
| 1 | 50.0 | 100.0 | 20    | out of range |
| 2 | 30.0 | 50.0  | 40    | ok           |
| 3 | 10.0 | 90.0  | 91    | out of range |
| 4 | NaN  | NaN   | 1000  | ok           |
```

My question is, is there a less expensive way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
df['boundary'] = ((df['min'] < df['value']) & (df['value'] < df['max'])) | (df['min'].isna() | df['max'].isna())
```

Timings:

```
771 µs ± 5.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Verus:

```
df["boundary"] = df.apply(lambda row: boundary(row), axis=1)
999 µs ± 11.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

You don't need to loop nor apply here because pandas will automatically line up that data on index to compare and will do this vectorized.